How to suppress terminal warnings when dockerizing a FastAPI LangChain application using the Gemini API?
Docker logs:
I'm working on a FastAPI application integrated with LangChain and using the Gemini API. I've dockerized the application, but when I run it, I encounter several warnings in the terminal that I'd like to address or suppress. The warnings are as follows:
2024-08-09 11:48:24 INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
2024-08-09 11:48:24 INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2024-08-09 11:48:24 INFO:     Started reloader process [7] using WatchFiles
2024-08-09 11:48:31 /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google_crc32c/__init__.py:29: RuntimeWarning: As the c extension couldn't be imported, `google-crc32c` is using a pure python implementation that is significantly slower. If possible, please configure a c build environment and compile the extension 2024-08-09 11:48:31   warnings.warn(_SLOW_CRC32C_WARNING, RuntimeWarning) 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:01<00:00,  1.16s/it]
2024-08-09 11:49:01 WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
2024-08-09 11:49:01 I0000 00:00:1723184341.297617       9 check_gcp_environment.cc:61] BIOS data file does not exist or cannot be opened.

What I've Tried:

I’ve verified that all the dependencies are installed in my Docker image.

I’ve tried to suppress the warnings using Python's warnings.filterwarnings("ignore").

I'm unsure if these warnings can be safely ignored, or if there’s a way to fix the underlying issues causing them.


What I'm Looking For:

How can I suppress or resolve these warnings?

Are these warnings indicative of a larger problem that needs to be addressed?

Is there a proper way to configure the environment or dependencies in the Dockerfile to avoid these warnings?

How to make my docker container properly?


